# change particular line chart series colour dynamically in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

try to change the colour dynamically for particular part in line chart but can't get any idea ,
[image]

```
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [ {
            value:3,
        dashStyle: 'solid',
        color:'#7cb5ec',
        fillColor:'#7cb5ec'
    },{
        value: 8,      
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        color:'#FFA262'
    }, {
            value:11,
        dashStyle: 'solid',
        color:'#7cb5ec',
        fillColor:'#7cb5ec'
    }]
}]
```

[here my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkpty4s/8/)

here i want to change the points(that have orange) colour in dynamic way in set of time interval i.e(5 sec)

please help me out to find the solution geeks

Comment: What do you want to change them to? When should it change, under what conditions? "In a dynamic way" does unfortunately not tell me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: want to achieve animation in those coloured lines to change their colour in particular time interval like 5 second or more,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically update the series' zones. You can do it with [Series#update()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update).

```
chart.series[0].update({
  zones: [{ ... }]
})
```

If you want to do it periodically use `setInterval()`.

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8gwh9yL6/

Comment: can we make redraw animation for that particular line ?